# Do - while loop stops when condition is not finished

Tags: c, do-while

I need to copy a two-dimensional array into a second, identically-sized array, but the while loops finishes before I want it to, and I don't know why.

Here is my code.

```
memcpy( array2, array1, sizeof(array1) );

do
{
    for( i = 0; i < rows; i++ )
    {
        for( j = 0; j < columns; j++ )
        {
            if( array1[i][j] == '!' )
            {
                if( array1[(i + 1)][j] == 'o' )
                {
                    array2[(i + 1)][j] = '!';
                    condition1 = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    condition1 = 0;
                }

                if( array1[(i - 1)][j] == 'o' )
                {
                    array2[(i - 1)][j] = '!';
                    condition2 = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    condition2 = 0;
                }

                if( array1[i][(j + 1)] == 'o' )
                {
                    array2[i][(j + 1)] = '!';
                    contidion3 = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    condition3 = 0;
                }

                if( array1[i][(j - 1)] == 'o' )
                {
                    array2[i][(j - 1)] = '!';
                    condition4 = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    condition4 = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    memcpy( array1, array2, sizeof(array2) );
    count++;
}
while( condition1 != 0 && condition2 != 0 && condition3 != 0 && condition4 != 0 );
```

I've checked the state of each of the 4 condition variables, but every time I print them out I recieve `1` for all of them. I will be grateful for any advice.

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: You have && in your conditions. That means if any of them are 0, loop will exit. If you need the what you describe change && to || (or)

Comment: Is i and j your global variables.?

Comment: Also check for border conditions: when i == rows-1 or when j == columns-1, trying to assign a value to the element [i+1][j] or to the element [i][j+1] will cause undefined behaviour. Most likely you will end writting into the memory assigned to other variable, causing lots of headaches while debugging that.

Comment: I just knew, from the title, that a complex, multi-step boolean expression, (ie. one that cannot be easily debugged), would be involved:(

Comment: Changing && to || solved the problem. Thank you guys and I'm sorry for making a question for this. I always thought that if I need all conditions to be done toghether, there must be &&. Thank you once again

Comment: Complex boolean expressions can be tricky, which is why I continually suggest that they are broken up and each sub-expression loaded into a temp boolean before the conditional.

Comment: when posting a question about a runtime problem, please post code that cleanly compiles, not some code snippet.

Comment: the posted code has undefined behaviour.  It can access memory before the array and after the array.  This is due to the lines like: `if(array1[(i+1)][j] == 'o')` (and many others) .  Suggest checking for array bounds before checking `i+1`, `i-1`, `j+1`, `j-1` offsets into the array

Comment: the use of the `&&` operator says all conditions must be true.  the use of the `||` operator says at least one condition must be true.

Comment: Is `array1` a pointer or an array?`  If pointer, `memcpy(array2, array1, sizeof(array1));` is suspicious.  Suggest posting both `array1, array2`definitions.